# exclude from rewrite rule, htaccess etc

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Hi all I have an htaccess with the following rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_env.c>
 SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
 </IfModule>

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
 RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

I want to add a rule that says to ignore these rewrite rules for the urls that are like:

```
www.site.org/URL
```

and everything after:

```
www.site.org/URL/*
```

To make them follow special rewrite rules found in an .htaccess file placed in URL folder.

How can I do?

Comment: Add line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/URL` directly above each `RewriteRule ...` line.

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^URL(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]` as first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line.